# Sum in columns, subtraction in grand totals - DAX

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I would like to see the sum of data in columns and subtraction in grand totals in an Excel pivot table based on Power Pivot, e.g. in the column "Suma końcowa" I would like to see subtraction A-B instead of sum.

Thanks for help!

[file](https://excelraport.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/DAX.xlsx)
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aRt4.png)

Comment: Hi do you want these values as Grouped or UN-grouped?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go for a option of pivot from table of data.

The fields which you have in the tables will converted as grouped for same Column when makes pivot table.
Hence the calculated Item doesn't work. So added **"Month"** Column by Using Formula of `=Text(value,"MMM'YY")`. The created the pivot table and done manual calculation.

**1.Added Month Column In Table :**

[image]

**2.Crating new pivot table based the Table data:**

[image]

**3.Pivot Table Created and Filed assigned based on required format:**

[image]

**4.Insert Calculated Item From analyze Tab:**

[image]

**5.Working on calculation Item option:**

- In The Insert Calculated Item View Type Name manually as 
  what you need the field header **ex. Subs**
- The In The Formula Tab Type **`= (A-B)`** else double click on the 
  **A** field and the  type **"-"** manually then double click on **B**
- Then  Click **Add** then the field "Subs" will be added In Pivot Table.

[image]

**6."Subs" Field added in pivot and removing Grand Total From Pivot Table:**

[image]

**7.Final view of Pivot with "Subs" field from table of Raw Data:**

[image]

> Note: Please read complete and view the images to understand better
>   way. The adding filed 
>         item not possible by making your own pivot style which is in your question image, 
>         due to the **Data** filed is in **Group** option.
>         So need to follow the steps which i have mentioned over above.
>
> Please let know though comments if need any more clarification.